# Parent class of my array

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have an object which contains an array.

Without coredate or a database, how do I model the relationship back to the parent from any of the children. Do I have to explicitly store the parent id in the child? Or is there a way to get the "parent" class of this array?

Answer (score 1):

Objective-C (unlike Qt and a few other object models) has no "parent-child" or "ownership" relationship.  Yes, sometimes we say that the object that retains an object "owns" it, but that's more of a shared ownership, since multiple objects can retain a given object, but none of the "owners" is more "distinguished" than the others and hence (in the plain Objective-C model) the "parent".

The first thing to consider is whether your "parent/child" concept really makes sense in this multiple-owner environment.  If so, then you need to maintain the child-to-parent pointers yourself, somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Without subclassing `NSArray` and adding an extra property, which I think is a bad idea, I guess you have two choices:

- Make the object at index 0 a pointer to your containing object
- Don't store your array directly in your "parent" object, store it in a `NSDictionary` which also has a `@parent` key, holding a reference to the parent.

To be honest I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve here - when would you need to find out this information that wouldn't be better done by simply working with the parent object itself?

**UPDATE**

I've just seen this answer to a separate question: [Create Custom UIButton class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391585/create-custom-uibutton-class/7391755#7391755)

Associative references sound like they could be what you need? You can associate a reference to your containing object to the NSArray. I don't know anything else about them, though, I just saw that answer and thought of this question.

Answer (score -1):

```
NSArray * array = [[NSArray alloc]init];
id parrent = [array super];
```

Comment: No, `super` is a keyword similar to `self`, not a method. And in any case, it doesn't refer to the containing object, but to the array's superclass.