# Create Custom UIButton class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I was wondering the best way to do the following,

1. Create many buttons.
2. Allow each button to be ID'ed by a custom made string.

I read that maybe subclassing UIView might work, but that subclassing UIButton would be quite impossible. Also if I were to subclass UIView and then fill the frame with a button, would adding say 50 of these to the screen cause any performance issues, obviously graphics would have something to do with that. But might there be an easier way?

I found it pretty easy to subclass the UItableviewcell, and i would like just a quick tip or snip'it of code to tell me how to something similar to a UIButton.

Thanks!

Comment: Why subclassing of button is impossible?

Comment: Well not impossible I guess, but I read on 3 different questions on here where people said not to do it.

Comment: Crazy variant: add `UILabel` as subview, hide it and save id in label text. What do you think about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to do this is to use the `tag` property of `UIView`. (`UIButton` is a subclass of `UIView`.) A `tag` is just an integer, so it is very suitable for loops and such things. Needless to say, it works with subclasses also.

This method also shows up in many of Apple's examples. It is convenient because you do not need to keep any other variables around. Also, there are very practical methods to access the buttons via `viewWithTag`:

```
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)[theSuperView viewWithTag:i];
```

I have for example implemented a piano keyboard in this way. To write an algorithm that identifies each key (or pitch) with the tag is quite simple.

Comment: That would work, although I need these buttons to be in a grid, so i was hoping for more coordinates. which a tag cannot hold

Comment: The coordinates can be stored in the button's `frame` property. You can also construct `tag`s that include the coordinate. E.g. numbers like `101103` for `{1,3}` could be dealt with using easy integer arithmetic.

Comment: how might you convert `101103` to `{1,3}`?

Comment: Come on ;-). `x=(i/1000)%100; y=i%100;` and you have `{x,y}`. Just press that accept button, would you?

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to subclass `UIButton`, then you can do it. However, you may run into problems if you make calls to `+buttonWithType` which instantiates subclasses instead of `UIButton` directly.

If all you want to is to add a custom `NSString` or other object to associate with each button, then you can use [Associative References](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocAssociativeReferences.html) to do this.

You can create many buttons at once using a `for` loop, possibly with the aide of an `NSArray` to hold the buttons if you do not want to add them to a subview right away.

Another approach is to create an `NSDictionary` where the objects are `UIButton`s and the keys are the `NSString`s by which you want to identify each button.

Comment: I took a look at Associative References, and I think thats just what i need, I just want to add a int value to each button I create so I can track their (x/y) coor. But i dont understand exactly how to set it to a UIButton or what `&overviewKey` exactly does. Could you help?

Comment: @James: If all you want is an `int`, then just set the `tag` property of each `UIButton`, e.g. `button.tag=42`.

Comment: That would work however want more than just a tag, I just thought that it would be easier to see an example of an int, and repeat the process to get what i want